# What font is being used for the Apple Watch?

Tags: font-identification, apple

[image: Apple watch screenshot 1]
[image: Apple watch screenshot 2]

Did Apple create an entirely new typeface for the Apple Watch? Did they customize something existing? To me it looks like it was inspired by DIN and given a very tall x-height, but I see influence from Roboto in there as well.

Comment: Should have been Comic Sans.

Comment: @Scott Apple Watch "Children" Edition? Not too late!

Comment: The text looks pretty close to Helvetica. The numerals aren't, though.

Comment: @DA01 Nah, I was watching the keynote and right away I noticed that the 'e' and 'c' glyphs didn't curve all the way around like Helvetica does. The 'R' and 'G' are very different too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever it is, it’s grotesque.

Seriously though, DIN does look close but for its square tittles and punctuation marks and not getting the 9’s right.

I fancy [Aktiv Grotesk](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/daltonmaag/aktiv-grotesk/) for a closer match on the numbers, but it’s just not ‘square’ enough and again lacks round tittles, etc.

UPDATE: Apple did indeed create their own typeface for the font: http://www.apple.com/watch/technology/#familiar

> We even developed a new typeface to maximize legibility.

Comment: Good catch on the website reference. I'll mark this as accepted until we get more details (I'd love to know about its name, the design process, etc.).

Answer (score 4):

According to the Apple Watch HIGs, it's a new font called [San Francisco](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/WatchHumanInterfaceGuidelines/ColorandTypography.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014992-CH9-SW1), and it comes in two flavors:

> Choose the San Francisco Text font for text that is 19 points or smaller. Choose the San Francisco Display font for text that is 20 points or larger.

Jon Gruber [notes](http://daringfireball.net/linked/2014/11/18/watchkit-hig) that it's not the first [San Francisco](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Francisco_(typeface)) font to appear on an Apple device, though this iteration is certainly a lot more practical!